# Do I use the definite article before a type of transport only when I use a certain type of transport on a regular basis?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Do I only use *the* before a specific transport only when I regularly use it. For example:

> I take **the** bus to work.

Let's say don't usually go somewhere by cab, but I decided to use it on one occasion. Do I still have to use *the*? For example:

> Yesterday I took **the** cab home yesterday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends partly on the context.

If someone asks you how you get to work and how you get home, you would normally reply:

> I take a bus to work
>   I take a cab home

But it is also common in English to talk about **the bus** when **a bus** is intended (and **the train** when **a train** is intended). It's a way of referring to **the bus service** and **the train service**.

This is especially the case when the context is about a familiar transport service.

So, if a friend complains about the poor bus/train service in the area, you might respond:

> I know. I take the bus/train to work every day.

You are not specifying which bus, only referring to using the bus service.

This device does not work for cabs. People do not talk about **the cab** unless they are referring to a specific cab. So you take **a cab** home in the evening.

However, you might inform your friend that you were late because **the cab** was held up in traffic. Here, you are not specifying which cab but it's clear that you are talking about the cab that you were in.

In short, it depends on the context and on familiar English expressions.

Comment: I would say "I go to work on the bus (_or_ by bus)".